# How to find the time where certain value is breached in R?

Tags: r

I would like to find the next occurrence ('Time') where minimum value ('MinValue') is breached.

For example, given the following sample of data:

```
Time <- c(1:10)
Value <- c(9,7,10,6,7,7,10,9,6,10)
MinValue <- c(5,6,8,4,6,6,8,6,4,9)
SampleData <- data.frame(Time, Value, MinValue)
```

I would like to achieve the following:

[image]

I would like to add column ('TimeMinValue') which show at what time the minimum value of the current row is breached.

Thank you all very much for your help! I have tried to look for my answer online but couldn't find anything. However, if I have accidentally duplicated a question then I apologise.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the logic behind. What do you mean by "breached"? And why is the first row `NA`?

Comment: By "breached", I mean when the value of the next observation is lower than the min value of the respective observation. The first row is NA because the min value of 5 is never breached in the next 9 observations. The lowest value of the next 9 observations is only 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there's a less convoluted approach, but one option would be `sapply` over rows with `which`:

```
transform(
  SampleData,
  TimeMinValue = sapply(
    seq_len(nrow(SampleData)),
    function(x)
      Time[
        which(Value <= MinValue[x])[which(Value <= MinValue[x]) > x][1]
        ]))
```

Output:

```
   Time Value MinValue TimeMinValue
1     1     9        5           NA
2     2     7        6            4
3     3    10        8            4
4     4     6        4           NA
5     5     7        6            9
6     6     7        6            9
7     7    10        8            9
8     8     9        6            9
9     9     6        4           NA
10   10    10        9           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this can be solved by a *self-join*.

Here are two different implementations using

1. `data.table`
2. `SQL` / `sqldf()`

#### `data.table`

The `data.table` version is a "one-liner" which *aggregates in a non-equi self join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(SampleData)[
  , TimeMinValue := .SD[.SD, on = .(Time > Time, Value <= MinValue), .(min(x.Time)), by = .EACHI]$V1][]
```

> ```
>     Time Value MinValue TimeMinValue
>  1:    1     9        5           NA
>  2:    2     7        6            4
>  3:    3    10        8            4
>  4:    4     6        4           NA
>  5:    5     7        6            9
>  6:    6     7        6            9
>  7:    7    10        8            9
>  8:    8     9        6            9
>  9:    9     6        4           NA
> 10:   10    10        9           NA
> ```

#### `SQL` / `sqldf()`

I was curious how this can be expressed in SQL syntax. The code is more verbose because we have to join twice:

1. a self-join which compares `MinValue` with `Value` in subsequent rows
2. a left join to complete rows and to find the `TimeMinValue` for each `Time`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf(
  "SELECT sd1.*, min(t) TimeMinValue
   FROM SampleData sd1 
   LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sd1.Time, 
                      sd2.Time t 
          FROM SampleData sd1 
          JOIN SampleData sd2
          WHERE sd1.Time < sd2.Time AND
                sd1.MinValue >= sd2.Value
        )
   USING (Time)
   GROUP BY Time  
")
```

> ```
>    Time Value MinValue TimeMinValue
> 1     1     9        5           NA
> 2     2     7        6            4
> 3     3    10        8            4
> 4     4     6        4           NA
> 5     5     7        6            9
> 6     6     7        6            9
> 7     7    10        8            9
> 8     8     9        6            9
> 9     9     6        4           NA
> 10   10    10        9           NA
> ```

#### EDIT: Improved `SQL` version

[G. Grothendiek has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660707/how-to-find-the-time-where-certain-value-is-breached-in-r#comment107354582_60667239) a streamlined SQL version which is much closer to the `data.table` version:

```
sqldf(
  "SELECT a.*, min(b.Time) TimeMinValue
   FROM SampleData a
   LEFT JOIN SampleData b
   ON a.Time < b.Time AND
      a.MinValue >= b.Value
   GROUP BY a.Time")
```

Comment: Thank you, @G.Grothendieck! This much leaner and comes closer to the `data.table` version.